# Projection map: change of coordinates

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety,and let $P\in\mathbb{P}^n$ be a point not in $X$.

By a change of coordinates we can assume that $P=[0:\cdots:1].$

> Question. what change of coordinates are we talking about? How can you write it explicitly?

Let $H\cong\mathbb{P}^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a linear subspace of codimension $1$ tha does not contain $P$; again by a change of coordinates we can assume that $H=\{x_n=0\}$.

> Question. what change of coordinates are we talking about? How can you write it explicitly?

Thanks!

Comment: A change of coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is given by an element of ($P$)$GL_n(K)$ (maybe not directly relavent but useful). The trick is to swap a non-zero coordinate with the last one, then just subtract an appropriate multiple of this from the other non-zero coordinates. Then check this is invertible by e.g., finding an inverse or equivalently showing the determinant of the matrix I mention is nonzero. In the second case we have $f(x_1,...,x_n) = 0$ so just find a chage that sets $f = x_n$

Comment: @MummytheturkeyThanks for your explanation, but unfortunately I didn't understand

Comment: For example if I want to move $P = (2,1,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$ I take $X' =X$, $Y'=Z$, $Z' = Y$ so that $P \mapsto (2,0,1)$ and then I set $X'' = X - 2Z$, $Y'' = Y'$ and $Z'' = Z'$. Composing these gives the appropriate change of coords.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3915313/unique-linear-transformation-carrying-projective-hyperplane-to-projective-hyperp), asked a couple days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\pi:\mathbb A^{n+1} \setminus 0 \to \mathbb P^n$ be the projection map, and let $v_0,..., v_n$ be a basis for the vector space structure $V$ induced on affine space by your choice of coordinates downstairs (the spans $\langle v_i \rangle$ are obtained as
$$
\langle v_i \rangle = \pi^{-1}(0:\cdots : 0 : \underbrace{1}_{i\text{-th entry}} : 0 : \cdots : 0),
$$

so just pick any nonzero vector therein). Then in particular $\pi^{-1}(P) = \langle v_n \rangle$. Similarly you can lift a given point $[a_0:\cdots: a_n]$ to the one-dimensional subspace $\langle a_0v_0 + \cdots + a_n v_n \rangle$. I leave it to you to write down a matrix that interchanges these subspaces.

The second change of coordinates is similar: choose a basis for $\pi^{-1}(H)$. Since $P \not \in H$, the union of this basis with $\left\{ v_n \right\}$ is a basis for $V$. The same is true if we start with $\pi^{-1}\left(\left\{ x_n =0 \right\}\right)$, choose a basis, and adjoin $v_n$. Thus there is a change of basis matrix for $V$ that will carry $H$ to $\left\{ x_n =0 \right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the  way to think about this is to realize that there's *nothing special* about any point in $\mathbb P^n$. The same goes for any (n-1)-plane in $\mathbb P^n$.

To expand upon @Mummy the turkey's comment: every point in $\mathbb P^n$ is represented by a point $\overline P$ in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$. There is always a linear transformation sending $\overline P$ to the point $(1, 0, \ldots, 0)$. An explicit example is found as follows: find a basis for $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ as a vector space, where $\overline P$ is the first vector. Make the matrix $A=[\overline P, \ldots]$. Then the matrix $A^{-1}$ takes $\overline P$ to $(1, 0, \ldots, 0)$.

All this  carries over to $\mathbb P ^n$ since matrix multiplication is linear.